# Why throwing the same product in Cart.has(product) it return false

Tags: lightning, json, javascript-controller

### Controller

```
  handleClickAddToCardEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
            let product = event.getParam("product");
            let Cart = component.get("v.productCart");
            if(Cart == null){
                Cart=new Map();
                alert('new map');
            }
            alert('Cart.has(product): '+Cart.has(product));
            if(Cart.has(product)){
                let IncreasedAmount = Cart.get(product)+1;
                alert('Cart.get(product)+1:');
                Cart.set(product,IncreasedAmount);  
                alert(''+Cart.keys()+':'+Cart.get(product));
            }else{
                Cart.set(product,1);  
                alert('else: '+Cart.entries());
            }
            component.set("v.productCart",Cart);
        }
```

product it's sObject Product2

Comment: Can you log the values for Cart and product and add them to the question. Likely your Cart is coming as null

Comment: In first try Cart is null(in if(Cart == null) I create new Map and add first product) and it's normal.But following try Map is not null(something inside) and I tried check use Cart.keys() ,.values(),.entries() it return [object Map Iterator]